# Multi value person picker in MOSS user profiles

Tags: user-profile, my-site, people-picker

I'd like to add a property to the user profile (mysites) that allows the user to pick multiple users from the people picker control. It looks like the Person control only accepts 1 value by default. How would I go about allowing multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the field only supports a single contact.  What is it you are ultimately trying to do or accomplish?  There may be another way.

Comment: We need to store 2 lists of users in the UserProfile, the same user can be in both lists, these will to be used by some custom code. Colleagues would have worked but it looks like 1 person can only be in 1 group.

Comment: You can always put it in a list that everyone has read only access to.  You could put a simple edit form on top of it on the User Profile page.

Comment: I was thinking I could add a string property to the profile and set it to hidden from the edit page. Then create a custom page that uses the standard People control to populate the property

Answer (score 0):

I don't where is the people picker that you are referring to?
First thought My sites Colleagues but double checked and accept multiple users
Anyway the People Picker support multiple users and you can change this from the column settings.

Hope this helps if not can you provide more info about where exactly is that people picker?

thanks

Comment: In SSP > User Profile and Properties > Add User Profile Property  .. When you chose type = Person you get the people picker control which only accepts one person